# Why does my props data object array print true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component where I pass in data via props which is later used to render a flatlist. I'm trying to save the data to state but after setState, 'data' is printed as 'true' rather than the object array that is received via props.data.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
const Slider = props => {
  console.log('props data', props.data) // prints [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.data)
  console.log('state data', data) // prints true
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be replicating properties as new state anyway. They're _already_ state coming in. Anything that's a prop should be managed in the parent component's state.

Comment: @isherwood that's not really true.  A component might render a list of data, passing the data of each element to the child component. If that data can be changed, it sometimes makes sense to initialize the child's state with the props passed in from the parent.

Comment: Sometimes. Not usually. It creates complexity and redundancy if it's not needed.

Comment: @isherwood agreed, but there are definitely cases where this happens and it's not that uncommon.

Comment: As I said, "probably". :) Mostly I'm looking for context to avoid an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You can only get these logs if during the initial render props.data = true, but then on subsequent renders props.data is your list. Likely you don't need the state at all, but we'd have to see a real example first.

Answer (score 0):

If you see below logs, you can see logs are proper.

Do check this snack too

https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/aa0c60

Hope it helps. feel free for use

[image]